# How to Select Whole Row of a table in Mvc5 using Single Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working in a School Management project.The structure is when i am adding any new item in my project i have a single graph table where every item is generating a unique Graph Id, now i am having Cart where user can buy a book from it and that Cart contains GraphId of the item.

My problem is i want to search all the tables in database where that Item GraphId match the graphId in every table it give me the json of whole row of the table in which it exits

```
var searchgraphId = from m in db.OfflineCarts select m;
            searchgraphId = searchgraphId.Where(s => s.UserId == loginuserinfoid);
            foreach (var c in searchgraphId)
            {
                graphId = c.ListOfGraphIds;

            }
```

This i have done where it will find all the graph ids belongs to login userid and it will get its carts item and now how to proceed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to search graph id in all tables individual

your search will be as like

```
var searchgraphIdInUser = from m in db.UserInfo where m.GraphId == graphId  select m;

            foreach (var c in searchgraphIdInUser )
            {
                 var user = db.UserInfoId.Find(c.UserInfoId)
                 // delete the row data here

            }
```